# Trying to clone mat-table nested datasource.data in angular

Tags: angular, tree, datasource, clone, angular-material-table

I'm trying to clone a nested data object to perform some specific operations on cloned data in angular. But after the operations are completed, I can see the update also made to original datasource.data.

I have tried:

1. the spread operator:

```
this.reservedDataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data];
```

2. structuredClone:

```
this.reservedDataSource.data = structuredClone(this.dataSource.data);
```

3. a separate functionality of deepClone ([found here](https://medium.com/@stheodorejohn/mastering-deep-cloning-in-javascript-handling-nested-objects-and-arrays-4de203463244)):

```
deepClone(obj: any): any {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
      return obj;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj.map(this.deepClone.bind(this));
    }
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
      return new Date(obj.getTime());
    }
    const clonedObj: any = {};
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        clonedObj[key] = this.deepClone(obj[key]);
      }
    }
    return clonedObj;
  }
```

4. and JSON.pares & JSON.stringify:(It also stringify all objects)

```
          this.reservedDataSource.data = JSON.parse(
            JSON.stringify(this.dataSource.data)
          );
```

But I've found common thing in all those methods, when in nested levels, the original dataSource.data is also getting updated. On one level they all work fine.
I need it to update only the clone data.

Answer (score 2):

Try lodash [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) instead!

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];
 
var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
```

Also except the 1st example. The other methods (2 and 4 will not have this caveat) please share a working stackblitz demonstrating this problem for debugging!

Comment: Thank you for the response but still facing the same problem, all properties are according to the plan, only one object's 'endDate' is getting updated in original dataSource.data, and due to this, all other objects are updated accordingly, I guess its a bug in my code:(

Comment: @FarazKhan please provide a stackblitz where the issue happens, also provide details on what needs to be fixed on the stackblitz!